# SQL divide 2 columns

Tags: sql, division

I need to calculate population density in SQL.  I have a column with population and a column with area but I'm can't figure out how to execute it, I get a division by zero error.

Here is what I tried:

```
select name, population, gdp, area, [population]/[area] as pop_density 
from country 
group by name 
order by gdp;
```

Comment: any area value in your table contains zero or null?

Comment: As Josh...... sad, there are some 0 values in area your data. You can fix it writing: case when area <> 0 then population/area end as pop_density.

Comment: There are, I tried to add a statement: where area>0 but I still couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: which database ?

Comment: I have added sample sql lite query for your reference.

Comment: @Trisha . . . What is the `group by` for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `nullif()`:

```
select name, population, gdp, area,
       population / nullif(area, 0) as pop_density
from country
order by gdp;
```

The `group by` doesn't seem necessary.

`nullif()` is a standard function that returns `NULL` when the two values passed in are equal.  If your database does not support it, you can do the same thing with a `case` expression.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need `group by`? 
There is no need for grouping. 
Even if you did need `group by` you couldn't select non aggregated columns like: 
`population, gdp, area`.
Just check for `null` or `0` for the column `area`:

```
select 
  name, population, gdp, area, 
  case coalesce(area, 0) 
    when 0 then null 
    else population / area 
  end as pop_density 
from country 
order by gdp
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add in `where clause as`

```
       select name, population, gdp, area, 
      [population]/[area] as pop_density 
        from country where area
       NOT IN (NULL,0) group by name 
     order by gdp
```

Or, You can handle your divisor area's value 0 via `Case` Statements...

```
  .......Case when Area IN (Null,0)
         then 0
          else
           [population]/[area]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select name, population, gdp, area, [population]/[area] as pop_density 
from country 
where area is not null and area is not 0
group by name 
order by gdp;
```

Comment: this would filter records which is not expected.

Comment: @Ram Ghadiyaram , Please read our comment, I have tried with sample online sqllite database. We asked user about sample data and database name.  He never mentioned or provided any answer to our comments. We can write different logic in different database. I hope this gives you some clarification.